# Select 30% of each column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Let's assume we have a table with a column 'A' that has values from 0 to N. And I want to select 30% each rows that have the same value for the column 'A'.

```
So if I have this:
A|  B
-------
0 hello
0 test
0 hi
1 blah1
1 blah2
1 blah3
1 blah4
1 blah5
1 blah6

Result:
A|  B
-------
0 hello
1 blah1
1 blah4
```

it could be blah1 or any other blah that is not blah4, and blah4 can be any other blah that is not blah1, basically it could be random or skipping.

By the way, the actual table is huge, talking terabytes, so think about performance.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It's not clear what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: Do you mean you want 30% of the rows? Like, if there are 100 rows, you want 30 of them? Which 30? Or so you mean you want 30% of the value in column A, grouped by column B? Your question is unclear

Comment: You need to define which 30%. The "first" 30%? Okay... then what determines the "first"-ness of a given row? You **must** have some criteria. Table order? There's no such thing... it's an illusion. Random? Sql Server doesn't do random well. SQL is designed for you to specify exactly which rows you want.

Comment: @MatthewPK based on the example, he wants your first option: show 30 percent of the rows.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ... I was about the junk the question and vote to close until I realized that, poorly formed as it is, I'm not sure *I* know how to return 30% of the rows :-D

Comment: Just use TOP with a PERCENT if that's all you need... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @mservidio but he doesn't want the top 30%. He wants 30% of each set with a shared 'A' value. So he wants 30% of A=0, 30% of A=1...

Comment: @SamDeHaan - I see, in that case looks like an answer has been provided that performs this already.

Comment: From the "Result", I think he wants every 4th record when column "A" matches?

Comment: the order doesn't matter, it could be random or ordered as long as its not repeated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (A int, b varchar(10))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'hello') --OP's data
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'test')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'hi')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah1')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah2')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah3')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah4')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah5')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah6')

;WITH NumberedRows AS
(   SELECT 
        A,B,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY A,B) AS RowNumber
        FROM @YourTable
)
, GroupCounts AS
(   SELECT
        A,MAX(RowNumber) AS MaxA
        FROM NumberedRows
        GROUP BY A
)
SELECT
    n.a,n.b
    FROM NumberedRows           n
        INNER JOIN GroupCounts  c ON n.A=c.A
    WHERE n.RowNUmber<=(c.MaxA+1)*0.3
```

OUTPUT:

```
a           b
----------- ----------
0           hello
1           blah1
1           blah2

(3 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** based on the great idea in the comment from Andriy M

```
;WITH NumberedRows AS
(   SELECT 
        A,B,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY A,B) AS RowNumber
            ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS TotalOf
        FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT
    n.a,n.b
    FROM NumberedRows            n
    WHERE n.RowNumber<=(n.TotalOf+1)*0.3
    ORDER BY A
```

OUTPUT:

```
a           b
----------- ----------
0           hello
1           blah1
1           blah2

(3 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** here are "random" rows, using Andriy M idea:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (A int, b varchar(10))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'hello') --OP's data
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'test')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (0, 'hi')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah1')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah2')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah3')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah4')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah5')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'blah6')

;WITH NumberedRows AS
(   SELECT 
        A,B,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY newid()) AS RowNumber
        FROM @YourTable
)
, GroupCounts AS (SELECT A,COUNT(A) AS MaxA FROM NumberedRows GROUP BY A)
SELECT
    n.A,n.B
    FROM NumberedRows           n
        INNER JOIN GroupCounts  c ON n.A=c.A
    WHERE n.RowNUmber<=(c.MaxA+1)*0.3
    ORDER BY n.A
```

OUTPUT:

```
a           b
----------- ----------
0           hi
1           blah3
1           blah6

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This seems to be skipping some values of a, I said it is a very large table. It started with 1 then 3 then 10, and should be 0 then 1 then 2...

Comment: No need to calculate `MAX(RowNumber)` separately, just add `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A)` to `NumberedRows`.

Comment: Do you want actual randomness or round-robin selection?

Comment: @Andriy M, I've updated my answer with your great idea, thanks!!

Comment: @luis, I've added `ORDER BY` in latest update. if you are still missing rows to help with the "missing" rows.

Comment: oh ok it wasn't ordered, now is there a way to do this but picking random non-repeated elements rather than just the first 10%, so more like a 10% randomly picked from the current A value?

Comment: @luis: I'm not entirely sure about this, but you could try `ORDER BY NEWID()` instead of `ORDER BY A,B` (in the `OVER` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()`).

Comment: @luis, you should really put things like `s there a way to do this but picking random non-repeated elements rather than just the first 10%, so more like a 10% randomly picked from the current A value?` in the original question

Answer (score 1):

This uses only one subquery, and thus a single pass through your set.

```
SELECT a
    , b
FROM 
    (
        SELECT A
            , b
            , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(    PARTITION BY A
                        ORDER BY b
                    ) r
            , COUNT(b)
                OVER(    PARTITION BY A
                    ) ct
        FROM @YourTable
    ) n
WHERE n.r <= n.ct * 0.3
```

As does this, although this always returns the top 3 if there are fewer than 10 and "extras" get posted to the first bins.:

```
SELECT A
    , b
FROM 
    (
        SELECT A
            , b
            , NTILE(10)
                OVER(   PARTITION BY a
                        ORDER BY b
                    ) tens                          
        FROM @YourTable

    ) n
WHERE tens <= 3;
```